# Error when connecting kSoap to Spyne The attribute '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}root' is not allowed

Tags: android, python, ksoap, spyne

I have a soap server written in python using spyne.  I have also created a soap client in python using suds.  It works perfect.  Here is the code for the server

```
class Personnel(ServiceBase):

@rpc(_returns=String)
def personnel(self):
    """Docstrings for service methods appear as documentation in the wsdl.
    <b>What fun!</b>

    @param name the name to say hello to
    @param times the number of times to say hello
    @return the completed array
    """
    employees_list = employees()
    employees_list.populate_from_db("elleo", "odoo", "0801", "127.0.0.1")

    tstString = "Dirk"

    return tstString

application = Application([Personnel], 'elleo.personnel',
                    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                    out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)
```

When connect with my android program using kSOAP, I get an error.  Here is the code:

```
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://192.168.1.100:8000/personnel";
    String METHOD_NAME = "personnel";
    String NAMESPACE = "elleo.personnel";
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.100:8000/?wsdl";


    try {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
  <faultstring>:1:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_COMPLEX_TYPE_3_2_1: Element '{elleo.personnel}personnel', attribute '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}root': The attribute '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}root' is not allowed.</faultstring>
```

Any idea how to solve this.  This is just a small program that I try to use to establish communications. I will expand the program if this part work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  I do not claim to understand why it work but it did.  See [How can you remove namespace declarations in ksoap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949020/how-can-you-remove-namespace-declarations-in-ksoap) for more details.

Here is the code that I added to my java program:

```
try {
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    soapEnvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

    Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```